# List comparison with different sizes

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
list1=['a','b','c','d']
list2=['c','d']
```

I have to compare this `list1` and `list2`

1. if `list1` and `list2` are same I should not remove any items and I have to keep the `list1` as it is. For example `list1=[a,c], list2=[a,c]` then `list1=[a,c]`
2. If `list1` has more elements than `list2`, I should remove the extra elements from the `list1` (as shown in the example), here I need `list1=['c']`
3. if `list1=['c']` then I should keep the `list1` as it is i.e. `list1=['c']`

How should I do it? I tried:

```
def is_equal(list1, list2):
    "Check both lists are same or not"
    return sorted(list1) == sorted(list2)
```

I am getting this error, I am not getting it all the time:

```
    return sorted(interviewers_name_list) == sorted(interviewers_list)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'NoneType'
```

Should I use loop to iterate it? Do I have any other easy way to do this list comparison?

Comment: Can you explain your case (ii)

Comment: What you describe in 1-3 means you can always use list2 ?!

Comment: In case (ii) for example list1=['a','b','c','d'] and list2=['a','c'] after comparison I need list1=['a','c'] because 'b' and 'd' are not in the list2

Comment: Yes, I will use list1 and list2 for comparison. if both are equal keep the list1 as it is. if list1 has more elements than list2 ,remove the elements which is not exists in list2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that your `list` would contain only unique elements, or that you are otherwise interested only in unique elements.

If that is the case, you should probably use [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).
There, the operation you are describing is the `.intersection()`:

```
a = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
b = {'c', 'd'}
print(b.intersection(a))
# {'c', 'd'}

a = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
b = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
print(b.intersection(a))
# {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}

a = {'c'}
b = {'c', 'd'}
print(b.intersection(a))
# {'c'}
```

---

Of course, if you start of from a `list` you could just convert it to `set()` via:

```
a = set([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(a)
# {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

---

Also, beware that `set`s do not have a defined order, so you may need to use `sorted()` on them (which will convert `set` to a sorted `list`).

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension might be what you are looking for. Here is an implementation which might help you.

```
list1=['a','b','c','d']
list2=['a','c']

if sorted(list1)==sorted(list2):
    print(list1)
else:
    print([elem for elem in list1 if elem in list2 ])
```

This should return the **output**

```
['a','c']
```

And if both the lists are the same, it just returns list1

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is what i understand from your explanation if two list are equal then it does nothing and simply returns list1, on the other hand if the elements in the lists are not same then it remove extra elements from list1 and make list1 similar to list2

```
list1=['a','b','c','d']
list2=['a','c']
def is_equal(list1, list2):
    "Check both lists are same or not"
    return sorted(list1) == sorted(list2)


def compare_list(list1, list2):
    if is_equal(list1, list2):
        return list1
    else:
        return sorted((set(list1) & set(list2)))

print(compare_list(list1, list2))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'c']
```